# How does NSIS installer track per-user installs

Tags: nsis, electron-builder

I built an NSIS installer for my electron app via electron-builder. Initially I had it per-machine, then changed it to per-user so user doesn't have to be an admin. I'm not sure of my steps of what exactly I installed during this transition (per-user vs per-machine) but at this point the installer always says that I have an existing per-user install located in "c:\program files...". I removed everything I can find from the registry and some related temp files, but this message in the installer will not go away. I can remove the per-machine install, and the installer will then correctly say that a new per-machine install is a fresh install. But if I do the same with the per-user install, the installer will always keep saying that there is an existing user install.

Anyone know where the info is kept about existing installs?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NSIS itself does not display a message like that nor does it track other installs (other than `InstallDirRegKey` which overrides the default install directory).

The message you see probably comes from electron builder. Inspect its template scripts to figure out what's going on.